# how to show the sub elements text based on div>a like the select>option structure in a drop-down box using original javascript

Tags: javascript, html

everyone. I got some problems when I wanna accomplish a drop-down box in a HTML website without using select and option elements, instead of using and elements.
The main function is made up by two parts, **the first function** is when clicked the first elements in the drop-down box, the hidden parts of list shows up and hide clicked again. **The second function** is when choose the elements in the hidden list, the text of the elements on the list will replace the first element on the drop-down box.

I have accomplished first function using below codes:

```js
// javascript codes

var searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_List");
var a_searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_List").getElementsByTagName("a");

function show(event) {
    let oevent = event || window.event;
    if (document.all) {
        oevent.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    else {
        oevent.stopPropagation();
    }
    // click it to show it, click again to hide it and loop
    if (searchListBtn.style.display === "none" || searchListBtn.style.display === "") {
        searchListBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.onclick = function() {
    searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
}

searchListBtn.onclick = function (event) {
    let oevent = event || window.event;
    oevent.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<!-- html codes -->
<html>
<body>
    <div>
 <div class="ui-search-selected" onclick="show();">A</div>
 <div class="ui-search-selected-list" id="btn_List">
  <a href="#">B</a>
  <a href="#">C</a>
  <a href="#">D</a>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I did the second part, my idea was not clear enough to implement that, I searched if I use select>option elements I could use selectedIndex method to find the index of list, but this is a custom drop-down box formed by div>a structure elements.

I tried to console.log(a_searchListBtn) and show an array from the console, and I could use a_searchListBtn[0~3].text to get the value of B/C/D.

I tried to write codes like below:

```js
a_searchListBtn.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Clicked.")
}
```

But nothing in the console, so, is there anyone could apply some help, thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're fetching all the a elements using `getElementsByTagName("a")`. Now you just need to loop through the results and add a click event listener that will take the innerHTML of that a element and put it into the innerHTML of the  ui-search-selected div.

You don't need an index. You can access the clicked element's innerHTML using `event.target`. See it working in this snippet below:

```js
// javascript codes

var searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_List");
var uiSearchSelected = document.getElementById("ui-search-selected");
var a_searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_List").getElementsByTagName("a");

for (button of a_searchListBtn) {
  button.addEventListener("click", replace);
}

function show(event) {
    let oevent = event || window.event;
    if (document.all) {
        oevent.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    else {
        oevent.stopPropagation();
    }
    // click it to show it, click again to hide it and loop
    if (searchListBtn.style.display === "none" || searchListBtn.style.display === "") {
        searchListBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.onclick = function() {
    searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
}

searchListBtn.onclick = function (event) {
    let oevent = event || window.event;
    oevent.stopPropagation();
}

function replace(event) {
  if (!event) return;
  uiSearchSelected.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML
  
}
```

```html
<!-- html codes -->
<html>
<body>
    <div>
 <div id="ui-search-selected" onclick="show();">A</div>
 <div class="ui-search-selected-list" id="btn_List">
  <a href="#">B</a>
  <a href="#">C</a>
  <a href="#">D</a>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I searched lots of similar examples and tried to use on my codes, and it works. But I use this.innerHTML to get the inner text, but also thank your sharing and let me know could use the event.target method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use this codes to implement this funtion, it works.

```js
// javascript
var par_searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_list_parent");
var searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_List");
var a_searchListBtn = document.getElementById("btn_List").getElementsByTagName("a");
// console.log(a_searchListBtn.length);
// console.log(a_searchListBtn);

function show(event) {

    let oevent = event || window.event;
    if (document.all) {
        oevent.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    else {
        oevent.stopPropagation();
    }
    if (searchListBtn.style.display === "none" || searchListBtn.style.display === "") {
        searchListBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.onclick = function() {
    searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
}

searchListBtn.onclick = function (event) {
    let oevent = event || window.event;
    oevent.stopPropagation();
}


for(var i = 0; i < a_searchListBtn.length; i++){
    a_searchListBtn[i].onclick = function () {
        par_searchListBtn.innerHTML = this.innerText;
        //searchListBtn.style.display = "none";
        
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- html codes -->
<html>
<body>
    <div>
 <div class="ui-search-selected" id="btn_list_parent" onclick="show();">A</div>
 <div class="ui-search-selected-list" id="btn_List">
  <a href="#">B</a>
  <a href="#">C</a>
  <a href="#">D</a>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```